# rubymineでスペースだけの行のスペースは保存時に削除したい

Tags: rubymine

コミットするときなどに、たまにスペースだけ残った行が入っていることがあります。
一行にスペースしかない場合はスペースを消したいのですが、
設定がみつかりません。

Answer (score 1):

これですね
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205803079-Configure-editor-to-remove-whitespaces-in-blank-lines

```
Settings | Editor | General | Strip trailing spaces on Save
```

の値を変更することで実現できます

Answer (score 1):

たまにということは、スペースが入っていない空行としてうまく処理されるということもあるということですよね。

`RubyMine 2017.1.1`
にアップデートしたところ私もたまにスペースが残ってしまうことがあります。

RubyMineは自動でファイルを保存してくれますが、どうもこの自動保存がうまくうごいていないように感じます。`Cmd-s`で手動で保存するとスペースが消えました。